# Are groups with the Haagerup property hyperlinear?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, geometric-group-theory, von-neumann-algebras, free-groups

In his 2008 paper *Hyperlinear and Sofic Groups: A Brief Guide*, Pestov asked (Open Question 9.5) whether every group with the Haagerup property is hyperlinear (or sofic). Has this question been answered in the meanwhile?

A short recap of the relevant definitions: A group is hyperlinear (sofic) if it embeds into the metric ultraproduct of unitary groups equipped with the normalized Hilbert-Schmidt distance (symmetric groups with the normalized Hamming distance).

A group has the Haagerup property if there is a sequence of positive definite functions that vanish at infinity and converge pointwise to the constant function $1$.

Comment: I believe this is still open.

Comment: For an irreducible lattice in a nonlinear Lie group such as a finite cover of $\mathrm{SU}(2,1)^k$ I guess hyperlinearity is unknown. (I'm not sure if non-residually finite lattices are known in such groups, but it sounds plausible).

Comment: It's not known if Thompson's group F is hyperlinear.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Especially @NarutakaOZAWA 's comment seems as good an answer I can expect. If you want to post it as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thompson's group $F$ has the Haagerup property [1], but it is not known if it is hyperlinear according to Narutaka Ozawa's comment.

[1] Farley. *Finiteness and CAT(0) properties of  diagram groups*. Topology, 2003.